# How do I pass a whole list data from a listbox without & with selection to controller?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, listbox

I can display the data on the listbox perfectly but I have no idea how to pass/post the listbox data (With & Without Selected) back to controller after I clicked the submit button. Is any way to do it without using jquery?

Here is my code on the View:

```
<%-- I have no idea what and how to pass data back to controller --%>
<%using (Html.BeginForm()){ %>
<%=Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.AvailableGroups, Model.AvailableGroup)%>
<%=Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.AssignGroups, Model.AssignGroup)%>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />    
<% } %>
```

In the model I declare the variable like this:

```
 public IEnumerable<string> AvailableGroups { get; set; }
 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvailableGroup { get; set; }

 public IEnumerable<string> AssignGroups { get; set; }
 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AssignGroup { get; set; }
```

This is the post action:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Update(EnrollGroup enrollgroup) { //I have no idea what kind of parameter type should I get in to this action
  //Perform my code here
 }
```

---

#### Solution

Since I unable to found any ways to return a whole list of the listbox, I assign a jquery function to  select all the data before submit the form. I changed the code under the submit button code:

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="selectAllItem()"/>
```

And it will return to the controller as model under AssignGroups variable.

Comment: Wondering why you mentioned "Is any way to do it without using jquery?"??? Normally on post, you will get the model data back in controller action. Are you not able to receive data in post action? Can you show your post action?

Comment: Most of the resource I search around the internet is using jquery to pass the data back to the controller. I have a difficulties on validate the forgery token while using jquery.

Currently I unable to post back to the controller, I dont know what parameter should I set on the post action function and how do I post it back. I need to get the whole set of data in the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ListBoxFor and it pertains to the object in your model, that should be captured in your HTTPPost

Comment: I tried to capture the data. But it only happened where I selected some of the item in the boxlist. I wish to get the whole list not only selected items. Thanks for reply

Comment: If I didnt select anything. the variable of AvailableGroups,AvailableGroup,AssignGroups,AssignGroup is null. After I selected some items in the listbox. the AssignGroups contain the same amount of data that I selected on the view.

Answer (score 0):

The below code selects the whole list. Just add it before the ajax call.

$("#myList option").prop("selected", "selected");